# How to access a structure variable which is inside a cpp class,from c?

Tags: c++, c

Sample eg:

messageStruct.hpp

```
class MessageStructure_t{

public:

struct MsgData_t {

   float a;
   int i;

}__attribute__((packed))msgdata_m;

};//classs end
```

I have a file in my project Application.c. I need to access the structure variables here.
Both are different, one .hpp and the other .c

How can I do this ?

Hoping your kind attention.

Comment: Note: .hpp and .c are just file extensions. You should rather talk about languages, if that is your concern, e.g. "How to access a C++ struct from a C module" or something like that.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have an instance of a C++ class and you need to access a data field from that instance from C. But this just begs the question how C accesses the object? Surely, C isn't able to pass class instances around. So what do you already _have_ in C?

Comment: i need to fill the classe's structure variable from the inputs i get..
which i am doing in c module

Answer (score 3):

You can define the struct in a separate header fine msg_data.h, and then include it in both projects. If needed you may have to typecaset the MessageStructure_t pointer into MsgData_t.

hence MsgData.h:

```
struct MsgData_t {
   float a;
   int i;
}__attribute__((packed));
```

messageStruct.hpp:

```
#include "MsgData.h"

class MessageStructure_t {
  public:
    MsgData_t msgdata_m;
}
```

Appliaction.c:

```
#include "MsgData.h"

//...
```

Comment: but I don't have the permission to change cpp class

Comment: This won't be enough since you cannot access the data in the class from C. This would need a free function. However, you cannot simply pass an object of the the class to that function, since C doesn't understand classes...

Comment: how about if I create dt structure's var in c using extern something like:
MessageStructure_t::MsgData_t obj_MsgData_t;

Answer (score 2):

When you want to access C++ classes and their objects from C, there are a few well-known patterns around. Google for them.

An easy one is to wrap it in a piece of OO C:

```
typedef void* my_handle_t;

handle_t create(void);  // returns address of new'ed object
void destroy(handle_t); // deletes object

MsgData_t* get_data(handle_t); // returns address of data in object
```

That leaves the question of how to make `MsgData_t` accessible from C. I see three possibilities:

1. move its definition into its own header (IMO best, but you already said you're not allowed to do it)
2. duplicate its definition (easy, but IMO worst alternative)
3. fiddle with the preprocessor (`#ifndef __cplusplus`) to make the C++ header accessible for a C parser (hackish, but avoids the code duplication of #2)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way would be to create an extern "C" function to access the structure.

Comment: But even this begs the question how to pass a class instance to that method from C.

Comment: @sbi I'm not sure what's so uncertain or mysterious about this.  You create `extern "C"` functions which wrap the methods.  If need be you can also write a `MessageStructure_Create()` to wrap `new` and the constructor(s), and `MessageStructure_Free()` to wrap `delete`.  Not sure what the type should be?  Do a `typedef` from `void*`.  You can write accessor functions for fields.

Comment: @asveikau: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138337/how-to-access-a-structure-variable-which-is-inside-a-cpp-class-from-c/2138546#2138546 `:o)`